# permission denied: /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, permissions

I'm trying to install java jre; I usually do it like this

```
sudo echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5CB26B26
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre
exit
```

but when I do

```
sudo echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I see

```
permission denied: /etc/apt/sources.list
```

When I do

```
ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I see

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3360 Aug 26 01:45 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

When I do

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.old | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I see

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: my question was asked 11 years ago and was closed as a duplicate of a question that was asked 10 years ago. Brilliant.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is a known issue; when you use `sudo` in this fashion, it won't work as you expect.  That is because while the `echo` command is run as root1, the `>>` for append is done by the shell, which is being run as a normal user, so when it tries to open the file target the permission issue comes up.

You can get around this in various ways, for example by using

```
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
```

or

```
echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

However, **it's safer to create a separate file for this source rather than editing the main `/etc/apt/sources.list` file**. To do that, you could use the same technique with `echo | sudo tee` like this:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/duinsoft.list
echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/duinsoft.list
```

This way, we leave the main `sources.list` alone, but the sources will be added via an included file that specifically handles this repository.  (This is how PPAs get added, by the way!)

Answer (score 27):

What happens with the command is that `echo` is run as root, but not `>>`. Try the following instead:

```
echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

alternatively, you could do it in two steps:

```
sudo -i

echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

exit
```

Answer (score 5):

What this command does is appending `deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Let's do it in an other method! Just open that file and append it manually!

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add `deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all` to end of it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit `nano`.

You can jump to the next command now...

Comment: Nice, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Create a script `myscript.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

execute it with (you have to give execute permission to it first e.g. `chmod u+x myscript.sh`)

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```